# What is recommended for fighting threats on an Ubuntu system?

Tags: malware, antivirus

I'm fairly new to GNU/Linux and I've recently migrated to Ubuntu because I've heard and read it's one of the best distros to try when you're learning Linux. However, I'm looking for something to minimize threats in Ubuntu. I've read and been told from multiple sources that you don't need to worry about viruses on Linux but my recent encounter leads me to believe otherwise.

I haven't had Ubuntu for long but I've already managed to get a rootkit on my system.  I've verified this from running sudo chkrootkit:

```
Checking `tcpd'...                                          INFECTED
```

So what do you suggest to make sure my system is secure in the Linux environment?  Should I just install an anti virus software of my choice or is there a better option(s) in Linux?  I would be willing to learn some programs rather than just taking the anti virus software route that does everything for you.

Comment: Three points: 1) minimizing threats strategy will depend on what sort of threats you expect and who is your adversary - that's what security professionals call "threat model". 2) `tcpd` is false positive, so you're safe from that 3) Read on [hardening Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/579954/295286) , [securing](https://askubuntu.com/q/190251/295286), [antivirus on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/10373/295286), and whatever else is linked to those questions.  Plenty of information.

Comment: Great, thanks for verifying tcpd isn't an issue and providing some links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is a common false-positive

> In [this Ubuntu Forums post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2346505&p=13583235#post13583235), user kpatz tested this in a fresh
>   16.10 VM and chkrootkit still complained, making this a false positive. You can always check if a file has been tampered by
>   comparing the md5sum from the package:
>
> ```
> $ dpkg -S /usr/sbin/tcpd
> tcpd: /usr/sbin/tcpd
> $ (cd /; md5sum -c /var/lib/dpkg/info/tcpd.md5sums)
> usr/sbin/safe_finger: OK
> usr/sbin/tcpd: OK
> usr/sbin/tcpdchk: OK
> usr/sbin/tcpdmatch: OK
> usr/sbin/try-from: OK
> usr/share/man/man8/safe_finger.8.gz: OK
> usr/share/man/man8/tcpd.8.gz: OK
> usr/share/man/man8/tcpdchk.8.gz: OK
> usr/share/man/man8/tcpdmatch.8.gz: OK
> usr/share/man/man8/try-from.8.gz: OK Of course, the md5sums file itself maybe tampered, (and so could `md5sum` itself and so on...).
> ```
>
> [1]:
>   https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2346505&p=13583235#post13583235

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/883501/474173)

There may be a slight difference, as in 18.04, instances of `tcpd` above will be replaced with `tcpdump`